# How to automatically find web services exposed on web about a special topic

Tags: spring-boot, web-services, coupon

How to find the available online web services for specific offers and coupons. I am charged to develop a webapp using spring boot, that well look on the web for available offers about a topic with some cretiria and consume these services.
Is there a way to find automatically web services exposed by websites, or I need to check desired sites.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look for some websites in the topic you desired and then contact their supports to ask them about their exposed services to the internet and to give you the endpoints of these web services.

Comment: Is this method automatically like asked in title? Would suggest leaving this answer as comment instead.